# Big O notation compare with itertools.product and for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two array of integers and I want to the minimum absolute difference between any elements from two array. I have two different way to do it. Both seems pretty much the same, but I do not understand what is Big O notitaion for two methods. 
are they both are O(mk)?

```
list1 = [1,3,7,12]
list2 = [11,39,9,-1]
from itertools import product
def method1(l1,l2):
    return min([abs(x[0]-x[1]) for x in product(l1, l2)])

def method2(l1,l2):
    num = []
    for i in l1:
        for j in l2:
            num.append(abs(i-j))
    return min(num)
print(method1(list1,list2))
print(method2(list1,list2))
```

Comment: its the same time complexity

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Both methods are exaclty the same

Suggestion for method1:

```
def method1(l1,l2):
    return min([abs(a - b) for a, b in product(l1, l2)])
```